# CSS resize image not accepting the parameters

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to resize an image. Bootstrap is enabled.

[image]

Here's my CSS:

```
/*Custom picture fix*/
@media(max-width:600px){
  .picturerow>img {
    width: 10px;
    height: auto;
  }
}
```

Here's my HTML:

```
<div class="picturerow">
    <ul>
        <li><img src="{{ asset('assets/img/icons-medium/facebook-medium.png') }}" alt="facebook-icon">  </li>   
        <li><img src="{{ asset('assets/img/icons-medium/linkedin-medium.png') }}" alt="linkedin-icon"> </li>   
        <li><img src="{{ asset('assets/img/icons-medium/twitter-medium.png') }}" alt="twitter-icon"> </li>   
        <li><img class="img-responsive" src="{{ asset('assets/img/icons-medium/xing-medium.png') }}" alt="xing-icon"> </li>   
        <li><img class="img-responsive"  src="{{ asset('assets/img/icons-medium/google-medium.png') }}" alt="google-icon"> </li>   
     </ul>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

The pictures should all be displayed inline, and for screen sizes of md and smaller (no less, sass etc) they should be displayed in the middle.
On the very small screens, the pictures should all be 15px width and keep the ratio.

Comment: I would like to also center the images within the div. What do I have to do??

Answer (score 1):

Probably the Bootstrap's class `img-responsive` is overwriting your custom class.

More importantly, when you use `>`, like in `.picturerow>img`, you're telling CSS that the images are a direct child of the picturerow div, which is false because you have `<ul>` and `<li>` before.

Comment: Thanks. How can I center the picturerow for small screens? I do not want float left in this case.

Comment: @Smiley `.pictureflow { width: 50px; margin: auto; }`

Comment: This does not work. @Press Also I do only want it for sizes smaller than 1200px eg. xs, md and sm .